# Problem with component default export / import in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am having trouble exporting/importing a component. Here is the error I get:

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `ContactState`.*

Here is my ContactState.js file that I export (code might seem weird as it's far from finished and with some dummy data in it).

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ContactContext from './contactContext';
import contactReducer from './contactReducer';
import {
  GET_CONTACTS,
  ADD_CONTACT,
  DELETE_CONTACT,
  SET_CURRENT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  UPDATE_CONTACT,
  FILTER_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  CONTACT_ERROR
} from '../types';

const ContactState = props => {
  const initialState = {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Jill Johnson',
        email: 'jill@gmail.com',
        phone: '111-111-1111',
        type: 'personal'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Sara Watson',
        email: 'sara@gmail.com',
        phone: '222-222-2222',
        type: 'personal'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Harry White',
        email: 'harry@gmail.com',
        phone: '333-333-3333',
        type: 'professional'
      },
    ]
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(contactReducer, initialState);



  // Add contact

  // Delete contact

  // Set current contact

  // Clear current contact

  // Update contact

  // Filter Contact

  // Clear Filter

  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider value = {{ contacts: state.contacts }}>
      { props.children }
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ContactState;
```

As you can see, I am not forgetting to export anything.

And here is my App.js file where I import ContactState:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import About from './components/pages/About';
import ContactState from './context/contact/ContactState';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  // Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <ContactState>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
              <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
      </ContactState>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried everything but nothing seems to work. I think the problem comes from this jsx ContactState tag.

Comment: Check `export` statements in `Home`, `Navbar` and `About` components.

Comment: here they are: 
```export default Navbar```
```export default Home```
```export default About```

Comment: Everything in the code you have posted in your question is apparently ok which suggests that problem lies in any other component. Double check the render methods of `Home`, `Navbar` and `About` components.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, double checked everything.

Comment: Can you create a demo of the problem in  codesandbox and share the link? This way anyone can test the problem and provide a solution

Comment: are you sure you are exporting the actual context constant as default from the contactContext file? `const ContactContext = React.createContext();` and `export default ContactContext;` Perhaps just render `{ props.children }` to check if it is the Context.Provider

Comment: Thank you so much Gandzal, it worked. There was definitely something weird with my context export (although I couldn't really figure out what).